# How to bind the cookie value to variable in knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, view

i am having a cooking name user and i want to access the cookie value in my knock out js  script file and assign it to a observable variable. how  can i do that?

```
var Suggestion = {
    SuggestionId: self.SuggestionId,
    Title: self.Title,
    CategoryId: self.CategoryId,
    ProductId: self.ProductId,
    Details: self.Details,
    StatusId: self.StatusId,
    CreatedDate: self.CreatedDate,
    CreatedBy: self.CreatedBy,
    ModifiedDate: self.ModifiedDate,
    ModifiedBy: self.ModifiedBy,
    UserId: self.UserId

};
```

i want to assign the createdby with the value in the cookie
  var userCookie = new HttpCookie("user", user.UserName);
how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your cookie is set with the [`HttpOnly`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_cookie#HttpOnly_cookie) flag you will not be able to access its value from javascript. You may inspect the value of `document.cookie` to know if you can see it. One possible solution in this case is to store the value of the cookie in some global javascript variable by a server side script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    @{ var cookieValue = Request.Cookies["user"] != null ? Request.Cookies["user"].Value : ""; }
    var user = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(cookieValue));
</script>
```

and then in your knockout script you could access this global variable:

```
CreatedBy: user,
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply i can able to see the value through document.cookie and i have created a global variable but still unable to get the value binded.as i am having script file and view seperately

Comment: If you can see the value in document.cookie, you can simply extract it from there. You don't need any global variable in this case.